# Move Data from Elastic Search to NSQ and then to a Mysql database

Tags: database, elasticsearch, nsq

I have a use case where we are using snowplow analytics to get data from various api's and webpages , due to some restrictions(snowplow) we are only able to get the data to ES through a NSQ channel.

Is there any way to move data from Elastic Search to a SQL database like posegres or mysql or through ES to NSQ and then to a MYSQL.

I tried to google a lot but i could get nothing looking for some sort of triggers on ES so that we can fill our mysql db based on that please help